# Css tooltip not sizing and wrapping nicely

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I have created a custom css tooltip, however the tooltip width is very narrow (only 1-2 words per line).

[Fiddle example of the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/3te7mz2c/)

I would like the tooltip size to be dynamically generated, as I will be using it in a few places with different lengths of text (the text may also change at a later date). Another reason I need it to be dynamic is that it needs to allow for browser resizing and mobile view.

I have done a bit of research and played around with (not limited to) the following properties:

```
width: auto; /*doesn't change anything*/
max-width: ;/*max and min not useful as I want it to be dynamic*/
min-width: ;
white-space: normal; /*neither change anything*/
text-wrap: normal;
```

None of the above seem to give me a solution.

I can't use bootstrap in this project, but I am able to add JavaScript if that offers a possible solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `.tool-tip-detail {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    color: #000000;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px #D1D1D1;
    font-size: 85%;
    display: inline-table;
    width: auto;
    white-space: normal;
    text-wrap: normal;
}`

In above CSS stylesheet, I observed that Position is absolute, Can you make it relative. And check the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative`. This, however, messed up some other dependent styling which would need to be fixed.

**Reasoning**: Absolute requires a width to be set whereas relative can be dynamic.